# Firebase Google Sign-In

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google sign-in through Firebase according to this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin. I got stuck on a problem with SHA-1 certificates and generating web client Id.
problem is  with steps 
 `4. If you haven't yet specified your app's SHA-1 fingerprint, do so from the Settings page of the Firebase console. See Authenticating Your Client for details on how to get your app's SHA-1 fingerprint.`

 and 
 `You must pass your server's client ID to the requested token method. To find the OAuth 2.0 client ID:
Open the Credentials page in the API Console.`
Since I added my SHA-1 for my project in Firebase I can not do the same in Google API Console - it gives me exception with duplicate entries for App package and SHA-1. I tried to enter them one way or the other but either Firebase or Google API console gives me this error. What is the proper way to solve this?

Comment: Go to firebase console > Settings > download `google-services.json` and put this file on app module level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well for those who get stuck at the same thing - once you enable Google sign-in in Firebase console, it generates it's own Web client Id, so you don't have to create credentials in Google API Console 
 
[image]